# What is hydration in angular

Tags: javascript, angular

Hydration comes to picture when change detection happens in angular. So What is hydration process and how it play change detection?

Now only there are 2 kind of change detection `default` and `onPush`. In my condition I need 3rd change detection where I want change detection to happen only when I want, not even change in `@input` variable.

Is there anything I can do in hydration process.

Comment: How is "change detection only when I want" related to "hydration". I guess what you are looking for is `ChangeDetectorRef.detach`

Comment: at what stage of component life cycle i can apply `ChangeDetectorRef.detach`

Comment: You can inject `ChangeDetectorRef` to your component/directive and detach in the constructor.

Comment: I see its document now! I think it will fit in my situation. Any idea on hydration process or any document where I can find in detail

Comment: I remember seeing it mentioned in error messages when components where removed/destroyed and event handlers were still firing (was probable a bug back then), otherwise I don't know what hydration is related to.

Comment: it's a 2D network of water  around a protein surface.